# Adding arguments to WooCommerce Product Loop using AJAX

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, ajax

I'm trying to make an AJAX product filter for my WooCommerce shop page. Previously, I had created the query myself, and didn't use the shop page. However, I want to make my code now more WC compatible.

At the moment, I can set variables from the query string to filter the WooCommerce Product loop.

I do this with the following code:

```
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_pre_get_posts' );
    function filter_pre_get_posts( $wp_query ) {
        if(is_shop()){
            $filter_term = $_GET['brand'];
            if (isset($filter_term ) && !empty($filter_term )) {
            $wp_query->set('tax_query', array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'pa_branding',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'terms' => $filter_term ,
                  'include_children' => true,
                  'operator' => 'IN'
              ),
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'terms' => $filter_term ,
                  'include_children' => true,
                  'operator' => 'IN'
              ),
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'terms' => $filter_term ,
                  'include_children' => true,
                  'operator' => 'IN'
              )
              ));
          }
        }
    }
```

I now want to be able to do the same thing upon clicking a checkbox.

On a checkbox being clicked, Javascript adds the value of the checkbox into an object with arrays:

```
var object = {
 'tags' : [],
 'priceRange' : [],
};

$('.checkbox-tag').change(function() {
  if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
    object.tags.push($(this).val());
  } else if($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
    var x = object.tags.indexOf($(this).val());
    object.tags.splice(x,1);
  }
  console.log(object);
  var formData = object;
  aJaxFilter(formData);
});
$('.checkbox-price').click(function() {
  if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
    var string = ($(this).val());
    object.priceRange = string.match(/\d+/g);
  }
  console.log(object);
  var formData = object;
  aJaxFilter(formData);
});
```

I then use Ajax to send this object.

```
function aJaxFilter(formData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: js_variables.ajaxURL,
        type:'GET',
        data: {
            'formData' : formData,
            'action' : 'listFilteredProducts'
        },
        success:function(data){
          console.log(data);
          $('.chd-shop-product-loop .products').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

What I'm trying to do now, is change the product loop, kind of like what I did with wp_query->set() using the parameters in the first chunk of code.

I tried to following in the Ajax function ->

```
add_action('wp_ajax_listFilteredProducts', 'listFilteredProducts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_listFilteredProducts', 'listFilteredProducts');

function listFilteredProducts($wp_query) {
  if(isset($_GET['formData'])) {
    $value = $_GET['formData'];
  }
  // If no price input, but tags have been input
  if ($value['priceRange'] == 0 && $value['tags'] != 0) {
    $wp_query->set('tax_query', array(
     'relation' => 'OR',
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => $value['tags'],
     ),
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => $value['tags'],
     ),
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'pa_branding',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => $value['tags'],
     ),
    ));
  //If price has been input, but no tags have been input
  } else if ($value['priceRange'] != 0 && $value['tags'] == 0) {
    $wp_query->set('meta_query', array(
      array(
          'key' => '_price',
          'value' => array($value["priceRange"][0], $value["priceRange"][1]),
          'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
          'type' => 'NUMERIC'
      )
    ));
  //if neither price or tags input
  } else if ($value['priceRange'] == 0 && $value['tags'] == 0) {
    $wp_query->set('post_type', 'product');
  // if tags and price input
  } else if($value['priceRange'] && $value['tags']) {
    $wp_query->set('tax_query', array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $value['tags'],
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $value['tags'],
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'pa_branding',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $value['tags'],
      ),
    ));
    $wp_query->set('meta_query', array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
           'key' => '_price',
           'value' => array($value["priceRange"][0], $value["priceRange"][1]),
           'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
           'type' => 'NUMERIC'
       )
    ));
  }
wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out now.

Instead of using $wp_query->set(), I instead set arguments, and then ran the woocommerce loop. This is the final code I used.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_listFilteredProducts', 'listFilteredProducts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_listFilteredProducts', 'listFilteredProducts');

function listFilteredProducts($wp_query) {
  if(isset($_GET['formData'])) {
    $value = $_GET['formData'];
  }
  // If no price input, but tags have been input
  if ($value['priceRange'] == 0 && $value['tags'] != 0) {
    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'tax_query' => array(
           'relation' => 'OR',
           array(
             'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => $value['tags'],
           ),
           array(
             'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => $value['tags'],
           ),
           array(
             'taxonomy' => 'pa_branding',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => $value['tags'],
           ),
          )
        );
  //If price has been input, but no tags have been input
  } else if ($value['priceRange'] != 0 && $value['tags'] == 0) {
    $args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => array($value["priceRange"][0], $value["priceRange"][1]),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            )
        )
    );
  //if neither price or tags input
  } else if ($value['priceRange'] == 0 && $value['tags'] == 0) {
    if(!$value['priceRange']) {
      $value['priceRange'] = array(0,1000000);
    }

    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'product',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
  // if tags and price input
  } else if($value['priceRange'] && $value['tags']) {
    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $value['tags'],
          ),
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $value['tags'],
          ),
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_branding',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $value['tags'],
          ),
        ),
            'meta_query' => array(
              'relation' => 'AND',
               array(
                   'key' => '_price',
                   'value' => array($value["priceRange"][0], $value["priceRange"][1]),
                   'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                   'type' => 'NUMERIC'
               )
             ),
          );

  }
  $ajaxposts = new WP_Query( $args );

  $response = '';

  if ( $ajaxposts->posts ){
    while ( $ajaxposts->have_posts() ) {
      $ajaxposts->the_post();
      $response .= wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); // use WooCommerce function to get html
    }
  } else {
    // handle not found by yourself or
    // perhaps do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' ); could do the trick?
  }

  echo $response;
  exit;
wp_die();
}
```